# Apache enruta Codeigniter en Windows, Mac pero no el Linux

Tags: ubuntu, codeigniter, apache, php8, codeigniter-4

Buen día, estoy haciendo una app en Codeigniter 4 usando apache como servidor. El detalle viene en que la computadora de mi trabajo es Windows (11) y el servidor al que subiré la información es GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 22.04). Teniendo esto, al momento de entrar a las URL de los controladores me marca en Linux el error 404 pero que en Windows no existe, ya que enruta correctamente. Lo probé en mi Macbook (M1) usando apache Homebrew y también enruta adecuadamente.

Ya intenté cambiando las configuraciones de `$indexPage` (añadiendo un '?' al final ) y `$uriProtocol` en sus 3 posibles opciones.

No es cosa de que cambien en cada sistema las configuraciones (aparte de `$baseurl`) ya que todo está en un repositorio y directamente clono los datos de ahí desde Windows a Linux y Mac.

Por si las dudas, dejo la configuración de enrutamiento:

**app/Config/App.php**

```
public string $indexPage = 'index.php';

public string $uriProtocol = 'PATH_INFO';
```

**app/Config/Routes.php**

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

El módulo rewrite de Apache en Linux está activado por lo que no puede ser tampoco eso. Ya no sé que hacer, espero puedan ayudarme.